# Changing Scenes in Corona objects stay on screen

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I have been modifying code from the memory match game to use scenes, sounds, and a 2d table. Adding the scenes has been the hard part. I have it set up to randomly select items from my 2d  table. Load those into a temporary table, shuffle them shuffle(), then boardSet(); to load their sounds and place them on the screen. Basically after the game is over I want the scene to reload or go back to the menu to start again. Selecting random data{} elements over and over.

I have tried returning to the menu, or going to a duplicate scene however I can't seem to correctly unload the objects created by my 2d array, as I can't properly add each item into a display group. I have tried everything I can think of. Right now my game loop is setup to add the play again btn that I want to restart the game after one match is found.

This link was a start in the right direction I believe with information about dealing with tables and groups. I still don't know how to cycle thru my 2d table to include everything in a group and then properly unload it.

http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/application-programming-guide-graphics-and-drawing#Variable_References

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- level1.lua
--
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local widget = require "widget"

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local image, text1, text2, text3, memTimer
-- forward declarations and other locals
local againBtn

-- 'onRelease' event listener for playBtn
local function onPlayBtnRelease()

    -- go to level1.lua scene

    storyboard.gotoScene( "menu", "fade", 500 )

    return true -- indicates successful touch
end

-- Preload the sound file (needed for Android)
--
local playBeep = function( testSound )
            media.playEventSound( testSound )
end
---Preload sounds

ki = audio.loadSound("ki-nawaneyoo.mp3")
u = audio.loadSound("u.mp3")
mayuhoo = audio.loadSound("mayuhoo.mp3")

--End Sound  Test

--Set Global width and height variables
_W = display.contentWidth;
_H = display.contentHeight;

---Count number of correct matches
local matchCount = 0;

--Hide status bar
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar);

--Declare a totalButtons variable to track number of buttons on screen
local totalButtons = 0

--Declare variable to track button select
local secondSelect = 0
local checkForMatch = false

--Declare Data Table
local data = {}
--Load objects into data
data[1] = {}
data[1].title = "Naka"
data[1].subtitle = "a"
data[1].image = "a.png"
data[1].image1 = "ear.png"
data[1].sound = "naka-ear.caf"
data[1].sound1 = "naka-ear.mp3"

data[2] = {}
data[2].title = "Aapuhu"
data[2].subtitle = "aa"
data[2].image = "aa.png"
data[2].image1 = "eyebrow.png"
data[2].sound = "aapuhu-eyebrow.caf"
data[2].sound1 = "aapuhu-eyebrow.mp3"

data[3] = {}
data[3].title = "Ego"
data[3].subtitle = "Ego"
data[3].image = "e.png"
data[3].image1 = "tongue.png"
data[3].sound = "ego-tongue.caf"
data[3].sound1 = "ego-tongue.mp3"

data[4] = {}
data[4].title = "Kamoo"
data[4].subtitle = "kamoo"
data[4].image = "ee.png"
data[4].image1 = "chin.png"
data[4].sound = "kamoo-chin.caf"
data[4].sound1 = "kamoo-chin.mp3"

data[5] = {}
data[5].title = "Kowpa"
data[5].subtitle = "ego"
data[5].image = "leg.png"
data[5].image1 = "leg.png"
data[5].sound = "kowpa-leg.caf"
data[5].sound1 = "kowpa-leg.mp3"

data[6] = {}
data[6].title = "Mae"
data[6].subtitle = "kwa"
data[6].image = "hand.png"
data[6].image1 = "hand.png"
data[6].sound = "mae-hand.caf"
data[6].sound1 = "mae-hand.mp3"

data[7] = {}
data[7].title = "Nodo"
data[7].subtitle = "kwe"
data[7].image = "kwe.png"
data[7].image1 = "throat.png"
data[7].sound = "nodo-throat.caf"
data[7].sound1 = "nodo-throat.mp3"

data[8] = {}
data[8].title = "Matogo"
data[8].subtitle = "kwe"
data[8].image = "kwe.png"
data[8].image1 = "thumb.png"
data[8].sound = "matogo-thumb.caf"
data[8].sound1 = "matogo-thumb.mp3"

data[9] = {}
data[9].title = "Matzehe"
data[9].subtitle = "kwe"
data[9].image = "kwe.png"
data[9].image1 = "elbow.png"
data[9].sound = "matzehe-eblow.caf"
data[9].sound1 = "matzehe-elbow.mp3"

data[10] = {}
data[10].title = "Kuku"
data[10].subtitle = "kwe"
data[10].image = "kwe.png"
data[10].image1 = "foot.png"
data[10].sound = "kuku-foot.caf"
data[10].sound1 = "kuku-foot.mp3"

--Declare button, buttonCover, and buttonImages table
local tableCopy = {}
local buttonImages = {}


--Shuffle data table
--local shuffleSet = function()
--Shuffle data table
math.randomseed (os.time())
local function shuffle(a)
        local n = #a
        local t
        local k
        while(n > 0) do
                t = a[n]
                k = math.random(n)
                a[n] = a[k]
                a[k] = t
                n = n - 1
        end
        return a
end

local tableCopy = shuffle(data);

local button = {}
local buttonCover = {}

--Choose six random objects from data to be used in game.
local firstSix = {}
for i = 1,6 do
    firstSix[i] = tableCopy[i];
end
local buttonImages = {firstSix[1],firstSix[1],firstSix[2],firstSix[2],firstSix[3],firstSix[3],firstSix[4],firstSix[4],firstSix[5],firstSix[5],firstSix[6],firstSix[6]}
--end


--Declare and prime a last button selected variable
local lastButton;-- = display.newImage("1.png");    
--lastButton.myName = 1;
--

--Set up simple off-white background


--Notify player if match is found or not
local matchText = display.newText(" ", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 65)
matchText:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint)
matchText:setTextColor(255, 255, 255)
matchText.x = _W/2


--
--Set starting point for button grid
local x = -20

local matchesFound = 0;

--Set up game function
local function game(object, event)
    if(event.phase == "began") then             
        if(checkForMatch == false and secondSelect == 0) then
            --Flip over first button
            buttonCover[object.number].isVisible = false;
            audio.play(object.sound);
            lastButton = object
            checkForMatch = true            
        elseif(checkForMatch == true and object.number ~= lastButton.number) then
            if(secondSelect == 0) then
                --Flip over second button
                buttonCover[object.number].isVisible = false;
                secondSelect = 1;
                --If buttons do not match, flip buttons over
                if(lastButton.myName ~= object.myName) then
                    audio.play(object.sound);
                    timer.performWithDelay(1000,function()
                    matchText.text = "Ki Nawa'neyoo";
                    audio.play(ki); end,1)

                    timer.performWithDelay(2500, function()                     
                        matchText.text = " ";
                        checkForMatch = false;
                        secondSelect = 0;
                        buttonCover[lastButton.number].isVisible = true;
                        buttonCover[object.number].isVisible = true;
                            end, 1)         

                --If buttons DO match, remove buttons
                elseif(lastButton.myName == object.myName) then
                    matchText.text = "U " .. object.myName .. " Mayuhoo";



                            audio.play(u)   

                            timer.performWithDelay(750,function()
                            audio.play(object.sound); end, 1)

                            timer.performWithDelay(1500,function()
                            audio.play(mayuhoo); end, 1)

                            timer.performWithDelay(2400, function() 

                            matchText.text = " ";
                            checkForMatch = false;
                            secondSelect = 0;
                            lastButton:removeSelf();
                            object:removeSelf();
                            buttonCover[lastButton.number]:removeSelf();
                            buttonCover[object.number]:removeSelf();
                            matchesFound = matchesFound + 1;
                            timer.performWithDelay(250, function()
                                if (matchesFound == 1) then
                            matchText.text = " Play Again? ";
                            againBtn.isVisible = true;

                            -- all display objects must be inserted into group
                            --group:insert( playBtn )
                            end
                            end, 1)
                            end, 1)


                end             
            end         
        end
    end

end
--]]
-- Touch event listener for background image
--[[
local function onSceneTouch( self, event )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        storyboard.gotoScene( "scene2", "slideLeft", 800  )

        return true
    end
end
--]]



-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local screenGroup = self.view

    local image = display.newImageRect( "bg.png", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    image:setReferencePoint( display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
    image.x, image.y = 0, 0

    screenGroup:insert( image )
    local function boardSet()
for count = 1,3 do
    x = x + 100 * 2
    y = 20 *2

    for insideCount = 1,4 do
        y = y + 90 * 2

        --Assign each image a random location on grid
        local temp = math.random(1,#buttonImages)
        button[count] = display.newImageRect(buttonImages[temp].image1, 150, 150);              

        --Position the button
        button[count].x = x;
        button[count].y = y;        

        --Give each a button a name
        button[count].myName = buttonImages[temp].title
        -- Preload the sound file (needed for Android)

        --Give each button a sounds

        soundID = audio.loadSound(buttonImages[temp].sound1)

        button[count].sound = soundID
        button[count].sound1 = soundID
        button[count].number = totalButtons

        --Remove button from buttonImages table
        table.remove(buttonImages, temp)

        --Set a cover to hide the button image
        buttonCover[totalButtons] = display.newImageRect("button.png", 150, 150);
        buttonCover[totalButtons].x = x; buttonCover[totalButtons].y = y;
        --screenGroup:insert(button[count].)
        totalButtons = totalButtons + 1

        --Attach listener event to each button
        button[count].touch = game      
        button[count]:addEventListener( "touch", button[count] )

    end
end


end
boardSet();
end




-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
againBtn = widget.newButton{
                            label="Play Again?",
                            fontSize = 25,
                            labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
                            default="button1.png",
                            over="button-over.png",
                            width=250, height=100,
                            onRelease = onPlayBtnRelease    -- event listener function
                            }
                            againBtn:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
                            againBtn.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
                            againBtn.y = display.contentHeight - 125
                            againBtn.isVisible = false


    print( "1: enterScene event" )

    -- remove previous scene's view
end
-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )

    print( "1: exitScene event" )
    if againBtn then
        matchText.text = " "
        againBtn:removeSelf()   -- widgets must be manually removed
        button = nil
        buttonCover = nil
        firstSix = nil
        data = nil
        tableCopy = nil
        buttonImages = nil
        againBtn = nil

    end


end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local screenGroup = self.view
    storyboard.removeScene();
    --storyboard.purgeScene( "level1" )

    print( "((destroying scene 1's view))" )
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene's view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched before next scene's transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Comment: Learned a bit more today about some of the 'pitfalls' when removing objects 'properly' here

Comment: Why can't you add them to the scene's screenGroup?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this is simple.

here is an example(assuming that you have implemented storyboard)

```
function scene:createScene(event)
    screenGroup = self.view
    local image = display.newImage("image.png")
    screenGroup:insert(image)
end
```

Now everything will go fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Add all the display objects to a group.`local myGroup = display.newGroup();
local img = display.newImage("yourimage.png");
myGroup:insert(img);`
For example

If you follow this method, all display objects will not be flushed out of memory when you change the screen.

Answer (score 0):

When using corona storyboard you need to add display objects to the group. For example you would need to add all of your display objects into screenGroup in order for them to be removed when you change scenes.